# Can my incoming water lines to water heater be reversed?

Tags: water-heater

I shut-off incoming cold water at top of water heater, disconnected the hot side in preparation for new install.  Opened house taps to bleed water lines. The next morning my garage was flooded. The water was coming from the hot side into garage.

Now I have confusion for new install, the side that flooded the garage appears to be the incoming cold--the line comes from the left when facing  the wall.  (I knew the house supply stop valve was not completely closed).

For install would I use the flood pipe for cold???

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. Some pictures of the piping and heater would really help here. If you can't edit them into your question, just edit in the URLs of the pictures and someone will be along to edit in the actual pictures.

Comment: Do any of the faucets in your house have mixer valves on them? The kind I'm referring to are where you have a single 'handle' to control both hot & cold. If you turn one of those on and there's no pressure on one side (hot) the other side (cold) could pass through ...

Comment: As @brhans says it sounds like back-feeding from someone using water.